# IndexMissingException[[mongodb] missing]

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Hi i am getting IndexMissingException[[mongodb] missing];

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166y.TransferQueue
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 38 more
[2014-09-25 12:30:12,257][WARN ][river.routing            ] [Night Thrasher] no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
[2014-09-25 12:38:43,392][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Night Thrasher] [_river] update_mapping [mongoindex] (dynamic)
[2014-09-25 12:38:47,401][WARN ][river.routing            ] [Night Thrasher] no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
```

Comment: Classic example of how not to ask a question, some context is needed to understand the problem; which is clearly lacking here.

Answer (score 0):

Its the version problem of river, mapper and my elasticsearch> iam using elatic search version 1.3.2 where as using mapper 1.3.0 and river 1.3.0 because of which i am stuck in missing index..